# Error while invoking android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to android and I am trying to create a listView with text and pictures and put it into the fragment. I created adapter for my list but when I try to set this adapter I get the following error. I would be glad if someone could help me find the solution to this problem.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Here is my code for this fragment

```
package com.example.gymshark;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.gymprogress.R;

public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView listView;
    String mTitle[] = {"Drink water", "Creatine"};
    String mDescription[] = {"Water", "Creatine"};

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mTitle, mDescription);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_notification, container, false);

    }

    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        Context context;
        String rTitle[];
        String rDescription[];

        MyAdapter (Context c, String[] title, String[] description)
        {
            super(c, R.layout.row_notification, R.id.text1, title);
            this.context = c;
            this.rTitle = title;
            this.rDescription = description;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_notification, parent, false);
            TextView myTitle = row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            TextView myDescription = row.findViewById(R.id.text2);

            myTitle.setText(rTitle[position]);
            myDescription.setText(rDescription[position]);

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the id 'listView' available in layout 'row_notification'

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56148035/7832102 and solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your XML is there available ListView with "listView" ID.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mTitle, mDescription);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_notification, container, false);
        this.listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your code in onViewCreated to onActivityCreated

instead of

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mTitle, mDescription);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Use this

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mTitle, mDescription);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem at

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_notification, container, false);
}
```

you are used wrong layout file so use your fragment layout file instead of `row_notification`